# How to create android jar project with src, res folder

Tags: android, jar, android-library, eclipse-adt

I want create android project use as jar library in another project with source and resources folder.

I have created demo project and export into jar by selecting src and res folder from eclipse. In my jar project contains view class that use layout xml file form resources of jar project.I added demo.jar in another project and run then it gives error.

If I am creating dynamic view without using any resources and use that jar project it work fine it .But I want to use resources of jar project in that view.

Comment: Now i have facing the same problem have found any solution for this

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do it with eclipse.

Read the following Android Reference [Setting Up Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).

Good Luck! :)